# Backbone event being called multiple times

Tags: backbone.js

I'm just getting my feet wet with Backbone, and I think I have an easy problem to solve.  I have the following view which is a simple tab that when clicked opens up a panel and when closed goes back to a tab:

```
myApp.views.Support = {
    Form: Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.el = $('#support');
            this._ensureElement();
        },
        render: function () {
            if (this.$el.hasClass('support-panel')) {
                // close panel
                this.$el.empty();
                this.$el.removeClass('support-panel');
                this.$el.addClass('support-button');
            }
            else {
                // open and populate panel
                var template = _.template(myApp.utils.RenderTemplate('support/default'), {});
                this.$el.removeClass('support-button');
                this.$el.addClass('support-panel');
                this.$el.html(template);
            }

            return this;
        },
        closePanel: function () {
            alert('close event fired');
        },
        events: {
            'click #SubmitFormButton': 'submitForm',
            'click #CloseSupportPanel': 'closePanel'
        },
        submitForm: function (event) {
            alert('form submitted: ' + $('#message'));
        }
    })
}
```

Everything is working fine except that "closePanel" gets fired +2 times every time the click event happens.  I assume it's some sort of cleanup I'm missing but I don't know what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely its because the event is bubbling up. Try returning `false`.

Comment: This worked, but doesn't seem like the "best" way to do it.  I completely admit that I absolutely have no basis behind that statement, and maybe that's in fact the proper way to handle this scenario.  What do you think?

Comment: its the right way to do it. thats just the way javascript works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it helped me realize what my issue was. Returning false as Daniel said works, but the root cause of my issue was having the jQuery selector twice in my markup, resulting in two jQuery objects being created thus the click event fires twice.